# Is it possible to use the jQueryUI dialog to pull in a HTML page similar to a traditional popup?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to come up with a way to load a url, (https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupAction!input.action in this case) in a jQueryUI dialog box instead of a traditional popup window.

So far, I've tried pulling in the page using an AJAX (AJAH :D) request, but each time, I get a status 200 but no data.

Here is the code from what I've tried: http://jsfiddle.net/Handyman/aXPU7/1/

I had thought that maybe the don't allow ajax requests to usps.com, but I tried a couple of my own sites with the same luck.

Is it even possible to do this without an iframe or a traditional style popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be easier to use a lightbox plugin like [colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXPU7/14/).

```
$('#zipcode_lookup').colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
```

Comment: *headpalms* I did some research and found what I was trying to do is prohibited by most browsers for security reasons, so looks like an iframe would certainly be in order.

Comment: I ended up just using the jQueryUI dialog with an iFrame: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Handyman/aXPU7/16/). It doesn't look too spectacular inside the jsFiddle window, but it looks pretty nice in my application :)

Comment: @Francis nice one. Always better to figure out some lines that work than load another library.

Comment: Is possible to use iscroll instead of css scroll in popup?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

In computing, the same origin policy is an important security concept for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and properties across pages on different sites.

You would need to use [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) or a proxy.